# How to show webpage on localhost to enduser on nginx?

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy

I am running two different service on an embedded device. One is at localhost:4444 and the other at localhost:8082.(the service at :4444 forwards a login attempt automatically to localhost:8082).

I want both of them behind nginx reverse proxy.

The nginx conf for the first service is as following

```
location /myauth {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:4444/oauth2/auth?client_id=client123;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_redirect http://localhost:8082/auth/ http://$host:8082/auth/;      
}
```

This works correctly. The flow is , I access the url `192.168.1.1/myauth` and I am redirected to `http://192.168.1.1/oauth2/` and then moved again to  `http://192.168.1.1:8082/auth/login?login_challenge=97eaa2ee59f8468b98d00bc0cb24b7b6`.

Problem is when I enter my login details and authenticate, I am moved back to `http://localhost:4444/oauth2/auth?client_id=testclient&login_verifier=a361d65d7f3742c78510a10a63d681d5&response_type=token` in my browser and since localhost:4444 doesnt exist on my workstation, that returns an error.

How can I remove the localhost from the last step and make nginx return the correct address?